# How to determine if two graphs are Isomorphic ? Finding a one to one and onto function.

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

I have these two graphs here:

[image]

I wish to determine if they are Isomorphic. I know that I need to find a one to one and onto function, however I can't find a way to do it.

My questions are:

1. I know that these two are isomorphic. What is the function f ?
2. In general, is there a way to find these functions ? Maybe using matrices ?

Comment: well, in this case, pick a vertex to match $u_1$.  Let's say $v_1=u_1$.  Now pick a direction to call clockwise and follow it around.  $v_1\mapsto v_3\mapsto v_5\mapsto v_2\mapsto v_4\mapsto v_1$ completes the identification.

Comment: In general, it's hard.  See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2486944/how-to-tell-whether-two-graphs-are-isomorphic)

Comment: The [Graph isomorphism problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem) is certified "hard" (NP-complete). This particular problem is not too hard. You need a bijection $f$ from $\{u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4,u_5\}$ to $\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5\}$ such that $f(u_i)$ is adjacent to $f(u_j)$ iff $u_i$ is adjacent to $u_j$.

Comment: If you could slide the vertices of the second graph around without breaking edges, can you make it look the first graph? That might help you find the function $f$.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang The graph isomorphism problem is not certified to be NP-complete. It is thought to be NP-intermediate, that is neither polynomially solvable, nor NP-complete. It founds an own complexity class of GI-complete problems. Closely connected but essentially different problem, the **sub**graph isomorphism problem, is known to be NP-complete

Comment: @Smylic You're right, of course. After I linked to the Wikipedia page I re-read it and found my mistake. But I had already closed the page and forgot to fix it.

Comment: Depth-first search often works well, although it takes exponential time in the worst case.   I can write up the details if you think that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

1. In this example there are multiple possible isomorphism functions $f$. For example $f(u_1) = v_1, f(u_2) = v_4, f(u_3) = v_2, f(u_4) = v_5, f(u_5) = v_3$, or $f(u_1) = v_2, f(u_2) = v_4, f(u_3) = v_1, f(u_4) = v_3, f(u_5) = v_5$, there are $10$ such isomorphism functions for these two labeled graphs. This number is different for different graphs. (It is known that [counting number of isomorphism functions is polynomially-time equivalent to checking existence of any](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0020019079900048?via%3Dihub).)
2. In comments you have a good link to the existing answer about how to do it. I want to add that graph matrices give you some invariants. Each of them can be used to show that some certain pairs of graphs are non-isomorphic. But none is known to be a criterion. Particularly, [there are pairs of non-isomorphic strongly co-spectral graphs](http://cs.yale.edu/homes/vishnoi/Publications_files/LVgraphpoly.pdf), that are co-spectral graphs with co-spectral complements. (Co-spectral graphs have the same spectrum of adjacency matrix.)

Answer (score 0):

For this problem swap the vertices $v_1$ and $v_3$ then move them both below $v_5$ and $v_4$. Now we're untangled the second graph so that it's also a pentagon. To construct our isomorphism $\varphi$ we first choose $\varphi(u_1)=v_5$ and map the cycle $u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4,u_5$ to the cycle $v_5,v_2,v_4, v_1, v_3$ which gives an isomorphism.

Note that this isomorphism is not unique as we can choose any vertex for $\varphi(u_1$) and we can also reverse the orientation of the cycle. For small graphs like this deforming one to look like the other is a simple way to find isomorphisms. You can see if we swap $u_4$ and $u_5$ then move them above $u_1$ and $u_3$ that they form the star so we could have deformed them the other way too.